# Express app with two versions of client

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I implemented an express application project with a server module and a client module. I have two versions of client - one for desktop and other for mobile devices. Only difference is in the layouting and internal routing done using Angular ui-router. Both versions are served with the same landing page by the use of `express.static` middleware of express.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/client"));
```

My server script is running on port 9000, as described in `server.js` as:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 9000;
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.listen(port, function () {....}
```

I start server by:

```
node server.js
```

and launch my homepage by:

```
http://localhost:9000
```

At present, I can only launch only one version of my client which is defined in argument passed in `express.static(__dirname + "/client")`. How can I launch two different versions of client from two different devices? How should I host my express app to take different root `__dirname` of client based on different devices?
Please help, I am a beginner in Node.js

Comment: How and where do you detect that the client is desktop or mobile?

Comment: Actually home page for both versions is same, which is a login page. But after logging in using mobile version app, it redirects to view-1. And after logging in using desktop version, it should redirect to view-2. It is all configured in respective application logic using angular routing. So, if I run these two versions separately with no change in server code, both run perfectly well. Because I explicitly tell server about the client using express.static middleware. But now I want to use both versions separately, being served by the same server. I'm not sure how to configure express server

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer

```
app.use('/desktop', express.static("path/to/desktop/site"));
app.use('/mobile', express.static("path/to/mobile/site"));
```

But in your description it does sound like both of the mobile and desktop site will be using the same website, and you just want a different url parameter. In that case you could to the following:

```
app.use('/desktop', express.static("path/to/website"));
app.use('/mobile', express.static("path/to/website"));
```

Now the `/desktop` and the `/mobile` endpoint will both render the same website. But you are now able to catch what endpoint the user used to access the website.

Answer (score -1):

You can send a `GET/POST` argument with every `GET / POST HTTP Request` , Exemple : 
In the login Post , In the mobile you send the `data + req.body.device == "mobile"` , in the other side , in the web , you send the `data + req.body.device == "web"` , 
with that you only need to verify ( in the server code ofc ) which type of device is sending the HTTP Request  , eg :

```
app.post("/login",function(req,res){
if(req.body.device == 'web'){
res.render('views1');
}else if(req.body.device == 'mobile'){
res.render('views2');
}
});
```